# When redirecting all URLs to homepage, what exceptions do I need to make?

Tags: redirect, wp-cron

I have a WordPress install that runs a few plugins purely as a backend. I want to completely hide the front end and just redirect it to the homepage. Should I redirect everything in htaccess and if so what exceptions should I allow? I assume there is a cron URL that should remain available?

Comment: Don't block wp-admin, wp-content if you want to be able to log in and edit anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution was to create a new theme with the basic files required for a theme, in the main PHP file just add a PHP redirect to the root domain. This ensures anything front end related goes to to the homepage, everything else stays the same.

For WooCommerce you have to put a redirect in a header.php file too.